# Use of Java regular expression, doesn't match *.jpg or *.gif

Tags: java, regex

[EDITED]
I'm using Java Regular expression and I don't want match some files.

I'm trying:

```
String regexp = "https?:://[[\\S]&&[^\"]]+(?!.*(.ico|.jpg|.css)"
```

I have a list with links from many websites, the links are: *.html, *.asp, *.jpg, *gif. I want use java regular expression to match everything but *.jpg, *gif, *ico.

Can someone give an idea?

Sorry, I'm not fluent in English.
Hope you can understand me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Try `"https?:://[^/]+"`. If that's not what you want, maybe you need to state your goal a little more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for my English.... 
The question is:
I want use regular expression to read a list of URLs and only print URLs from "real" pages, .html, .asp, etc... links like .ico, .jpg, .gif or .js aren't necessary!

Comment: What makes you think "real" pages will or will not have a specific extension?

Comment: I only know the list contain all the links from a web site, including files and images, if some file is a page, ok, can match, but images aren't important...

Comment: And what makes you think that only URLs with specific extensions have specific types?  For example, it is perfectly acceptable for `http://example.com/index.html` to give you a GIF or JPEG.

Comment: Try `String regexp = "^https?://(?!.*\\.(ico|jpg|css)$)[^\\s\"]+$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of program small program that will parse match links for a website but will exclude specific extensions.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(https?://[\\S^\"]+(?<!\\.ico|\\.jpg|\\.css))[\\s\"]";

        String test_string = "http://www.regular-   expressions.info/shorthand.html "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.css "                          
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.ico "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.jpg "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.htm "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.jsp "
                + "http://www.regular-expressions.info/ ";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(test_string);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.printf("Match: '%s'\n",  m.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the results:

```
Match: 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html'
Match: 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html'
Match: 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.htm'
Match: 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.jsp'
Match: 'http://www.regular-expressions.info/'
```